# Updating ToolsVersion="12.0" in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, updates

I am trying to compile a project written in C++. The compiler gave me this error.

```
1>Project file contains ToolsVersion="12.0". This toolset is unknown or missing. You may be able to resolve this by installing the appropriate .NET Framework for this toolset. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="4.0".
```

Can someone tell me How to resolve this error. I tried to update it but was unable to do so?

Comment: Maybe project you are trying to load was created at VS2013?
VS2013 has compiler version 12.0, VS2012 - has version 11.0, and may not know about 12.

Comment: You can create new project, add there sources and dependencies, and build it.

Comment: or search web for tools that can convert VS2013 to VS2012. If that is reason of problem.

Comment: VS2012 uses tools version "4.0", VS2013 uses "12.0".  There may be additional stuff in the .vcxproj file to give you a headache, sounds like you've already been editing it.  Something you should *always* mention in a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to compile a Visual Studio 2013 Project (as it uses ToolsVersion=12.0) on Visual Studio 2012 (uses ToolsVersion=11.0).

So here is the solution to Your problem. #TestedSuccessfully

1. In your Project Folder open the  .Vcxproj  file and change
   ToolsVersion=12.0  with 11.0
2. You have to change 12.0 with 11.0 at 3 places hopefully. You can
    check for all occurences and You are done.

**It worked for me. I hope will also work for You :)**

Comment: Yes it worked :D hurrahh

Comment: I think it should be `ToolsVersion="4.0"`, not 11.0.  It seems they jumped a few versions from VS2012 to VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

ToolsVersion "12.0" means that it is a Visual Studio 2013 project file.  You need to compile it with the correct compiler.

Comment: Can't I update it in Visual Studio 2012 ?

Comment: @up You will have to change toolset to lower in solution settings.

Comment: @OverKiller  can  please tell me the path. I am unable to fine it.Thanks

Comment: @farhangdon is right, check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) for details.